# Should rails be using gems from different paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Am currently getting a seg fault error when in rails console and trying to access active record.

Thing.first would cause a seg fault with the below at the top of the backtrace.

I am wondering if it has something to do with the gem paths, the top 2 paths in the trace below are different. Should they be using `/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems`?

Here is the top of the backtrace:

```
-e:1:in `<main>'
/Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
```

Comment: Rubygems is the gem's manager so it makes sense it's not inside the gems folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.4.0 is know for seg faults.
2.6.5 is the current released version, I would highly recommend you work from this version.  I have found this fixes many of these random seg faults.